# Rails 4 render collection in partial via escape_javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partials, kaminari

I have the following code which I'd like to render via javascript (Kaminari pagination via AJAX):

```
<div id="paginator-jobs-top" class="text-center">
  <%= paginate @jobs, remote: true,
                       theme: 'twitter-bootstrap-3',
                  param_name: 'jobs',
                      params: { tab: 'jobs' },
            pagination_class: 'pagination-small pagination-centered' %>
</div>
<div id="jobs">
  <%= render partial: 'jobs/job_panel', collection: @jobs, as: :job %>
</div>
<div id="paginator-jobs-bottom" class="text-center">
  <%= paginate @jobs, remote: true,
                       theme: 'twitter-bootstrap-3',
                  param_name: 'jobs',
                      params: { tab: 'jobs' },
            pagination_class: 'pagination-small pagination-centered' %>
</div>
```

And I was trying with this js.erb code but its not working at all:

```
$('#paginator-jobs-top').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@jobs,
                                                          remote: true, 
                                                           theme: "twitter-bootstrap-3",            
                                                          param_name: "jobs",   
                                                              params: { tab: "jobs" },
                 pagination_class: "pagination-small pagination-centered").to_s) %>');

$('#jobs').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "jobs/job_panel", 
                                           collection: @jobs, 
                                                   as: :job) %>');
```

I tried other variations but none of them worked. If anyone knows how to render the above code in a js.erb method I'd love to hear!

The error I get from above is:

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

When I try it with a slightly different line in the js.erb snippet (without ', job: j') I get:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `job' for #<#<Class:0x
```

**** Based on on Blelump's suggestion below I changed my code to this ***

```
<div id="jobs">
  <%= render partial: "jobs/job_panel", collection: @jobs, as: :job %>
</div>
```

Which works great without AJAX (this is actually the correct way to render collection partials in Rails, my mistake before). However when I adjust the js.erb file to this I still get an error:

```
$('#jobs').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "jobs/job_panel", 
                                           collection: @jobs, 
                                                   as: :job) %>');
```

The error is from Kaminari again:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `current_page' for nil:NilClass:
  kaminari (0.16.1) lib/kaminari/helpers/action_view_extension.rb:18:in `paginate'
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: One error I get is:
NameError - undefined local variable or method `job' for #<#<Class:0x0000010a2d4208>:0x00000108af5330>
A different error with another attempt:
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#jobs').html('<%=raw @jobs.collect {|j| escape_javascript(render :partial => "jobs/job_panel", :locals => {:job => j}) }.join("") %>');
```

or simpler, rendering a collection

```
$('#jobs').html('<%=raw escape_javascript(render :partial => "jobs/job_panel", :collection => @jobs, :as => :job) %>');
```

Comment: Better but still not working, I've edited my original question to incorporate your info.

Comment: It looks like it comes from `<%= paginate @elements %>` as stated here: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/kaminari/helpers/action_view_extension.rb . Did you provided corrent variable name?

Comment: Yes, I mean when I turn off the 'remote: true' option and run it, the pagination works fine both with my original way of looping and your suggestion of rendering a collection partial. All is ok. But as soon as I turn on 'remote: true' and transfer that snippet into show.js.erb it starts acting up. I will add more code... maybe its something else I'm doing.

Comment: Within your controller action, are you using `request.xhr?` or `respond_to` ?

Comment: No but you can use Kaminari without respond_to .js in my experience. In the controller I just call:

@jobs = Kaminari.paginate_array(@array).page(params[:jobs]).per(5)

Comment: In another project I've gotten 'remote: true' Kaminari pagination to work with controller variables in the absence of a respond_to block. This is absolutely certain.

Comment: Plus there is no issue when I remove 'remote: true', it works exactly as expected. Except I'd ideally want to avoid a full page refresh which is why anyone does ajax pagination, right?

Comment: Well, as states in kaminari docs, `remote: true` only adds `data-remote="true"` to the link so it is not the case here, you can add it manually. When you click second or third page, what comes to your controller? Does the input look the same for JS and HTML request? Are you paginating twice? In your `js.erb` is `paginate()` and what's in your controller, `Kaminari.paginate_array`?